# storing username from session to database while form submission using php

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a simple question,

I have a login and workspace area.

After the user logs in It shows the username of the logged in user at workplace as what I wanted. Now my problem is when user finish filling form available in his workspace the form is then stored in database also i need the username that is coming from session also get stored to the database.

here is code that is storing username and maintaining session after user reach at workspace after login:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/MainProject/connect/auth.php');
session_start();
 ?>
```

The final version of the updated insert file :

```
 //This code is included to check session and store username
 <?php
 require_once('..\connect\auth.php');
// session_start();
$usern = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
 ?>
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('main_project') or die (mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['WID'])){
for ($ix=0; $ix<count($_POST['WID']); $ix++)
{
    $WID = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['WID'][$ix]);
    $website = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['website'][$ix]);

    //var_dump("<pre>", $_POST['cat']); die();   // Debugger for checking cat counter.
    // $cat = implode(",", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat'][$ix]));       

    if(is_array(@$_POST['cat'][$ix]))
    $cat = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', @$_POST['cat'][$ix]));
    else
    $cat = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['cat'][$ix]);   

    $email = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['email'][$ix]);
    $cform = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['cform'][$ix]);
    $contactp = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['contactp'][$ix]);
    $contacts = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['contacts'][$ix]);
    $fax = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['fax'][$ix]);
    $Ctype = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['Ctype'][$ix]);
   $usern = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['usern'][$ix]);

    $sql_res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO website_01data (WID,website,cat,email,cform,contactp,contacts,fax,Ctype,TimeStamp,usern) 
    VALUES ('".$WID."', '".$website."', '".$cat."', '".$email."','".$cform."', '".$contactp."', '".$contacts."', '".$fax."', '".$Ctype."', Now(), '".$usern."' )");

$sql_res = mysql_error();   

}//end for..

echo "<p><span style=\"color: red;\">Thank You; your records are sent to database. DO NOT REFRESH THE PAGE or data will be sent again.</span></p>"; 

}
?>
```

Comment: where you get username and store in session?

Comment: $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];

Comment: Please add complete code in question.so i will find where is problem.

Comment: updated, kindly have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the logging in process, you must store your username in a session

`$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`

in the process of saving the form, you can call session_start(); and get the session using
    `$tobeinserted = $_SESSION['username'];`

I believe

Comment: someone has edited it with wrong meaning .. please re-read the question that what i required.

Comment: Please read my answer again. I've updated it. please tell if I got it wrong

Comment: Can you include your code on the question?
You might have syntax error or sort.

Comment: As I've seen from your comment.
You can call it from
$_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] ;

Comment: i tried this: $usern = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];  and then INSERT statement to save $usern to db location but i got an error.

Comment: You got the code right. Please include <?php session_start(); ?> before using $_SESSION.
What error does it show?

Comment: `$usern = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['usern'][$ix]);`
delete this part so that your $usern doesn't get replaced with null value

Comment: so instead of that what should i include in INSERT statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove comment in session start.

Use this.

```
//This code is included to check session and store username
<?php
require_once('..\connect\auth.php');
session_start();
$usern = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
?>

<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('main_project') or die (mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['WID'])){
for ($ix=0; $ix<count($_POST['WID']); $ix++)
{
 $WID = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['WID'][$ix]);
 $website = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['website'][$ix]);

//var_dump("<pre>", $_POST['cat']); die();   // Debugger for checking cat counter.
// $cat = implode(",", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat'][$ix]));       

if(is_array(@$_POST['cat'][$ix]))
$cat = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', @$_POST['cat'][$ix]));
else
$cat = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['cat'][$ix]);   

$email = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['email'][$ix]);
$cform = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['cform'][$ix]);
$contactp = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['contactp'][$ix]);
$contacts = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['contacts'][$ix]);
$fax = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['fax'][$ix]);
$Ctype = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['Ctype'][$ix]);
//$usern = mysql_real_escape_string(@$_POST['usern'][$ix]);

$sql_res = mysql_query("INSERT INTO website_01data (WID,website,cat,email,cform,contactp,contacts,fax,Ctype,TimeStamp,usern) 
VALUES ('".$WID."', '".$website."', '".$cat."', '".$email."','".$cform."', '".$contactp."', '".$contacts."', '".$fax."', '".$Ctype."', Now(), '".$usern."' )");

$sql_res = mysql_error();   

}//end for..

echo "<p><span style=\"color: red;\">Thank You; your records are sent to database. DO NOT REFRESH THE PAGE or data will be sent again.</span></p>"; 

}
?>
```